# How to attach multiple files to Laravel 8 Mail from laravel Excel 3.1

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-8, laravel-mail

I am trying to send 2 files attached to my mail but it is only attaching the first file and not the second file at the mail...

**What I have been trying:**

Mail Controller:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Content;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Envelope;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

use App\Exports\ProductInventoryExport;
use App\Exports\SalesReport;
use App\Exports\CustomerOrderReceipt;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;


class DailyReports extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the message envelope.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Envelope
     */
    public function envelope()
    {
        return new Envelope(
            subject: 'Daily Reports',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the message content definition.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Content
     */
    public function content()
    {
        return new Content(
            view: 'mails.daily-reports',
        );
    }


    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('sendmail@gmail.com')
        ->markdown('mails.daily-reports')
        ->attach(
            Excel::download(new ProductInventoryExport, 'ProductInventory.xlsx')->getFile(), ['as' => 'ProductInventory.xlsx']
        )
        ->attach(
            Excel::download(new SalesReport('daily', 0, 0), 'DailySalesReport.xlsx')->getFile(), ['as' => 'DailySalesReport.xlsx'], 
            //It's not attaching this file Idk why...
        );
    }
}
```

I am Calling the function like this:

```php
use App\Mail\DailyReports;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
public function sendMail()
{
    Mail::to('tomail@gmail.com')->send(new DailyReports);
}
```

**Results:**

Here, it only attaches the first file (ProductInventory.xlsx)...

The mail I am receiving:

[image: The Mail]

I tried a few other methods like **putting my files in an Array and looping through it but I got the same result that it's only sending the first file...**

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you try to attach the SalesReport first and then the ProductInventoryExport?

Comment: @SamiAkkawi , 
Then only the SalesReport file is attached... I tried doing that too :/ I just can't get it to attach both files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you cannot attach 2 downloaded files, even though 1 works. Unsure *why* that is.

You need to use `store` instead (https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/store.html).

What you can do is create a disk in `config/filesystems`, for example:

```
        'excel' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root'   => storage_path('app/excel-downloads'),
        ],
```

Then change the build method inside your `DailyReports` to:

```
    public function build()
    {
        // Store exports and add their file names to attachments array
        $attachments = collect([]);

        $fileName = 'ProductInventory.xlsx';
        // Arguments here are export, file name and the disk to store it to. You could also leave out 'excel', then it would be stored inside your default disk.
        Excel::store(new ProductInventoryExport, $fileName, 'excel');
        $realAttachments->push($fileName);

        $fileName = 'DailySalesReport.xlsx';
        Excel::store(new SalesReport('daily', 0, 0), $fileName, 'excel');
        $realAttachments->push($fileName);

        // Start build email
        $email = $this
            ->from('sendmail@gmail.com')
            ->markdown('emails.daily-reports');

        // Attach the files to the email
        foreach ($attachments as $fileName) {
            // Adjust the next line based on where you store the files
            $email->attach(storage_path() . "/app/excel-downloads/" . $fileName);
        }

        return $email;
    }
```

Here's the code without comments if you use the default disk to store the Excel files:

```
    public function build()
    {
        $attachments = collect([]);

        $fileName = 'ProductInventory.xlsx';
        Excel::store(new ProductInventoryExport, $fileName);
        $realAttachments->push($fileName);

        $fileName = 'DailySalesReport.xlsx';
        Excel::store(new SalesReport('daily', 0, 0), $fileName);
        $realAttachments->push($fileName);

        $email = $this
            ->from('sendmail@gmail.com')
            ->markdown('emails.daily-reports');

        foreach ($attachments as $fileName) {
            $email->attach(storage_path() . "/app/" . $fileName);
        }

        return $email;
    }
```

Comment: How can I delete the files created after a mail is sent??? Or else won't there be a lot of files storing every day while the DailyReport function runs?

Comment: That's a different question entirely already :D

Off the top of my head one option would be to create a command that runs periodically and deletes all the files in the folder.

Another option would be to send an event after the email is sent which triggers a listener which deletes the just stored files.

Or maybe there is a way to store them temporarily. 

Also keep in mind where you store the files and whether they should be accessible publicly or not.